# Darts tournament or Dart tournament?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

When referring to tournaments that involve darts, what is the preferred term in American English? Is it a darts tournament or a dart tournament?

Comment: If it was simply a singular/plural issue related to using "dart" as a modifier of tournament, it would be "dart".  However, the game is called "darts", so it is a "darts" tournament.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cambridge dictionary the correct usage for American English is **darts**
Having read this and also being from Britain I would have to say that this is the word used in the UK. (although after a couple of beers who cares).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Who's after a bit of cricket or 401?